# rails sum multiple fields

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, grouping

I'm trying to do this supposingly simple operation in rails:

```
self.timesheets.select("sum(total) as total, sum(quantity) as quantity").first where self is a project
```

When I do it in console mode, it works but it renders me 3 columns:

```
[#<Timesheet id: nil, quantity: 120.1, total: 6245.2>]
```

When I run it in the app, I get this error message:

```
PG::GroupingError - ERROR:  column "timesheets.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ..."  WHERE "timesheets"."project_id" = $1  ORDER BY "timesheet...
                                                             ^
:
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:811:in `prepare_statement'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:772:in `exec_cache'
  schema_plus (1.3.1) lib/schema_plus/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:231:in `exec_cache_with_schema_plus'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:139:in `block in exec_query'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:885:in `select'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:24:in `select_all'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `block in select_all'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:76:in `cache_sql'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `select_all'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/querying.rb:36:in `find_by_sql'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:585:in `exec_queries'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in `load'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:325:in `find_first'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:90:in `first'
  activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:129:in `first'
  app/models/project.rb:27:in `recalc_spendings'
  app/models/timesheet.rb:44:in `escalate_sums'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:452:in `_run__1475279931726113629__save__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:106:in `save'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
  app/controllers/timesheets_controller.rb:73:in `block in create'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:363:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:189:in `respond_to'
  app/controllers/timesheets_controller.rb:72:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:463:in `_run__3822865716334379624__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:50:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:28:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:42:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  remotipart (1.0.5) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:30:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1689713881852047757__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
  ruby-debug-ide (0.4.22) lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in `debug_program'
  ruby-debug-ide (0.4.22) bin/rdebug-ide:110:in `<top (required)>'
  -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm not really surprised by this message as the id is added to the query'result.

But why is it added by activerecord and how can I solve this?

Thanks!

EDIT

Thanks to PriteshJ, I understood that the ID was included by the "first" statement added at the end of my query to tell activerecord that it is a single record, not a collection.

So I know that I must get rid of first clause but when I do this, I get another error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `total' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Timesheet:0x007fe73da50470>
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:121:in `method_missing'
```

This is normal because it is looking into a relation instead of a single record but I don't know how to solve it.

Should be simple though...

Comment: PLS GIVE COMPLETE ERROR MSG

Comment: complete message uploaded

Comment: added a solution pls show the bunch of code that around with query  called from rails app

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are ordering the results by `timesheets.id` or you have some default order scope  or somewhere you are adding a order.

Remove the ordering or add the column to select by which you are ordering the query.

**UPDATE:**

try using

```
self.timesheets.select("sum(total) as total, sum(quantity) as quantity").to_a.first
```

`.first` in activerecord will try to sort the query and pick first element so first by using `.to_a` take the result first then do `.first`

Comment: You are completely right. The problem comes from this order by clause. I didn't even notice it... But it has been added by activerecord. It is not in my code anywhere. Strange...

Comment: Actually, the order by is due to the fact that I added "first" at the end of my statement. self.timesheets.select("sum(total) as total, sum(quantity) as quantity").first  I pasted a different version. Sorry about that. But without the first, I get another error message: undefined method `total' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Timesheet:0x007fad13c11cc8>

Comment: I tried it before. It puts the entire activerecord object into an array. Impossible to manipulate...

Comment: ?? I did not get what your problem you face in this query can you update the problem in question

Comment: yes it will put the object in array and so you have to pick the first as always it will have only one entry in array

Answer (score 2):

I think `select` is not the method you want to be using since you're not actually selecting a row in the db.

Perhaps [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) is what you want (If I understand the problem correctly).

Would this work for you?:

```
total = project.timesheets.sum(:total)
quantity = project.timesheets.sum(:quantity)
```

Comment: This is my temporary solution but I want to save to cost of an additional query.

Answer (score 0):

With [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) gem, it is easy.

```
self.timesheets.select{[sum(:total).as(:total), sum(:quantity).as(:quantity)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.timesheets.pluck("sum(total)", "sum(quantity)")`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `select` it will attempt to build a model with the fields you specified. You would be better of using `pluck` as suggested by jackpipe. However, I would make one alteration - methods like `sum` will return 0 if there are no records, but pluck will return nil, so to overcome that you could try this:

```
total, quantity = self.timesheets.pluck("sum(total)", "sum(quantity)").first.map(&:to_i)
```