# Sum on multiple columns with Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to Activerecord. I want to do sum on multiple columns of a model Student. My model student is like following:

```
 class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :class, :roll_num, :total_mark, :marks_obtained, :section
 end
```

I want something like that:

```
 total_marks, total_marks_obtained = Student.where(:id=>student_id).sum(:total_mark, :marks_obtained)
```

But it is giving following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `except' for :marks_obtained:Symbol
```

So I am asking whether I have to query the model two times for the above, i.e. one to find total marks and another to find marks obtained.

Comment: can you show your model , and what column your table has ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @mbratch I am getting  NoMethodError: undefined method `except' for :total_marks_obtained:Symbol

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use raw SQL if you need to. Something like this to return an object where you'll have to extract the values... I know you specify active record!

```
Student.select("SUM(students.total_mark) AS total_mark, SUM(students.marks_obtained) AS marks obtained").where(:id=>student_id)
```

For rails 4.2 (earlier unchecked)

```
Student.select("SUM(students.total_mark) AS total_mark, SUM(students.marks_obtained) AS marks obtained").where(:id=>student_id)[0]
```

NB the brackets following the statement. Without it the statement returns an Class::ActiveRecord_Relation, not the AR instance. What's significant about this is that you CANNOT use `first` on the relation.

```
....where(:id=>student_id).first #=> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "students.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: should note here that the aliased column name should match with one of the actual column names in the table

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work on all occasions, for example trying to select on an association or on a joined table with `includes()`.  I found you can actually supply aggragate functions in `pluck()`, eg
`Student.pluck("sum(total_mark)", "sum(marks_obtained)")`
as answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41606066/2067695

Answer (score 29):

You can use [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) to directly obtain the sum:

```
Student.where(id: student_id).pluck('SUM(total_mark)', 'SUM(marks_obtained)')
# SELECT SUM(total_mark), SUM(marks_obtained) FROM students WHERE id = ?
```

You can add the desired columns or calculated fields to `pluck` method, and it will return an array with the values.

Comment: Just want to add that this will return an array nested inside of another array (in Rails 4.2, at least), so remember to call `flatten` on the result.

Comment: This seems to be quietly converting floats into integers for me.

Answer (score 21):

If you just want sum of columns total_marks and marks_obtained, try this

```
Student.where(:id=>student_id).sum('total_mark + marks_obtained')
```

Comment: This is pretty sweet!

Answer (score 3):

Another method is to [`ActiveRecord::Calculations.pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) then [`Enumerable#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) on the outer array and again on the inner array pair:

```
Student
  .where(id: student_id)
  .pluck(:total_mark, :marks_obtained)
  .map(&:sum)
  .sum
```

The resulting SQL query is simple:

```
SELECT "students"."total_mark",
       "students"."marks_obtained"
FROM "students"
WHERE "students"."id" = $1
```

The initial result of `pluck` will be an array of array pairs, e.g.:

```
[[10, 5], [9, 2]]
```

`.map(&:sum)` will run `sum` on each pair, totalling the pair and flattening the array:

```
[15, 11]
```

Finally `.sum` on the flattened array will result in a single value.

---

**Edit:**

Note that while there is only a single query, your database will return a result row for each record matched in the `where`. This method uses ruby to do the totalling, so if there are many records (i.e. thousands), this *may* be slower than having SQL do the calculations itself like noted in the accepted answer.

Comment: You can use `pluck` to obtain directly the sum: `Student.where(id: student_id).pluck('SUM(total_mark)', 'SUM(marks_obtained)')`

Comment: @AlexGuti Please submit that as an answer - not just a comment!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the accepted answer, however, I'd suggest using arel as follows to avoid string literals (apart from renaming columns, if needed).

```rb
Student
  .where(id: student_id).
  .where(Student.arel_table[:total_mark].sum, Student.arel_table[:marks_obtained].sum)
```

which will give you an `ActiveRecord::Relation` result over which you can iterate, or, as you'll only get one row, you can use `.first` (at least for *mysql*).

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I also had the requirement to sum up multiple columns of a `ActiveRecord` relation. I ended up with the following (reusable) `scope`:

```ruby
scope :values_sum, ->(*keys) {
  summands = keys.collect { |k| arel_table[k].sum.as(k.to_s) }
  select(*summands)
}
```

So, having a model e.g. `Order` with columns `net_amount` and `gross_amount` you could use it as follows:

```ruby
o = Order.today.values_sum(:net_amount, :gross_amount)

o.net_amount     # -> sum of net amount
o.gross_amount   # -> sum of gross amount
```