# Rails count sum avg for multiple columns, not group by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails.

I know that 'group' on multiple columns is OK. But I don't want that, I want count (or sum, or avg) on multiple columns.

I know:

```
issues = Issue.group(:tracker_id).count(:subject)
```

have the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`issues`.`subject`) AS count_subject, tracker_id AS tracker_id FROM `issues` GROUP BY tracker_id
```

But it only count one column 'subject'. I tried to add one more column (status_id) as 2 statements below, but they don't work:

```
1. issues = Issue.group(:tracker_id).count(:subject).count(:status_id)

2. issues = Issue.group(:tracker_id).count(:subject, :status_id)
```

How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this with `ActiveRecord` methods alone.  But checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21916203/2622934) for info on how to do it with a little bit of SQL.

Comment: U can use in a controller....@var=Issue.find_by_sql("select count(subject) from issues")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to:
[group by + sum on multiple columns in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855821/group-by-sum-on-multiple-columns-in-rails-3)

I can do with some SQL:

```
issues = Issue.group(:tracker_id)
        .select([:tracker_id, "COUNT(subject)", "COUNT(status_id)"])
```

Don't know is this the best?